# Select first value over threshold or max in group

Tags: postgresql

I have data that looks something like this:

| time | value | replicate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0.812 | 1 |
| 3 | 0.9 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.2 | 2 |
| 2 | 0.3 | 2 |
| 3 | 0.4 | 2 |

And I want to find the duration when the values first cross a threshold value and the first value, in this case let's say it's 0.8 for each replicate group. However if a group doesn't have any value greater than the threshold, just return the max value.

Wanted output would be:

| duration | replicate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Is this even possible to do in a single query in Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select time, max(value)
from ...
where value > 0.8
group by replicate,time

union

select time, max(value)
from ...
where value < 0.8
group by replicate, time
```

Comment: you are right, but I realized that my question is poor. I don't actually need the value, I need the duration between the first value over the threshold and the first value in the group. Sorry for the confusion.